# Inconsistency between Kibana and elasticsearch rest api search output

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana-4, elastic-stack, filebeat

I've setup ELK Stack. When I query for certain type of log event in kibana it gives me 20 results since start and that is the correct result, but when i query for the same type of log event using rest query either using curl it returns only 10 results. not sure what is wrong here.. Please note i am querying for a string in message field on both sides. 
My Curl query: looks something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?q=message:Request%20to%20Service%20timed%20out%20for%20product?human&pretty'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curl query has some issues, you have `?` twice and you're missing a `size` parameter (by default only 10 results are returned)

Try this instead:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?q=message:"Request%20to%20Service%20timed%20out%20for%20product"&size=100&pretty'
```

Comment: you a re the man!!..On that can u also suggest how to use wildcard in between? so i want to request something like this "Request%20to%20Service%20timed%20out%20for%20product*someText" which should match all the records having someText as well